# UITabBarControllerDelegate - Where to put the Code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, ios7.1

I am writing an iPhone app with the following structure (created in storyboard)

```
UIView --> TabBarController --> 1.NavigationController --> UITableView --> UIView
                                2.NavigationController --> UITableView --> UIPageController --> UIView
                                3.NavigationController --> UIView
                                ...
                                7.NavigationController --> UIView
```

When a TabBarItem is clicked, I want the page to pop to the root view.

I know I need to implement a `UITabBarControllerDelegate` with the method:

```
- (void)tabController:(UITabBarController *)tabController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController *)viewController
```

I don't understand where to put this method and whether to make AppDelegate the UITabBarDelegate, or to make my customTabBarController class the delegate.

Also, where do I make the `tabBarController.delegate = self` call?

I'm a serious noob, please help :)

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboards

Comment: Are the viewControllers connected to the tabBarController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AppDelegate has the reference to the UITabBarController, then make that your delegate.